# unbind click then bind and again unbind it and bind it back..repeat

Tags: jquery

I'm adding pixels on click of a button to the 'div' children. When clicked on medium, it should add 1px and when clicked on large should add 2px. And user not allowed to click on the same button twice so I'm unbinding the click and binding it again, and this should happen when clicked on a button, the problem I am facing, I am not able to unbind it again after binding it back.

Here's the code:

html:

```
     <a id="small">Small</a>
     <a id="medium">Medium</a>
      <a id="large">Large</a>


     <div>
            <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
            <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
            <h4>ipsum dolor sit lorem</h4>
     </div>
```

jquery:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){


  function inc(){
       $("div").not("header div").not("footer div").children().each(function() {
      var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));

    size = size + 2 + "px";
    $(this).css({
'font-size': size
 });
 });
  }

   function med(){

      $("div").not("header div").not("footer div").children().each(function() {
      var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    size = size + 1 + "px";
    $(this).css({
'font-size': size
  });
  });
   }

  function small(){
      $("div").not("header div").not("footer div").children().each(function() {
      var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    size = size + 0 + "px";
    $(this).css({
'font-size': size
   });
   });
  }


  $("#large").on("click",function() {

inc();
$("#large").unbind("click");
    $("#medium").bind("click",function(){
     med();
   });
   $("#small").bind("click",function(){
    small();
   });


});

  $("#medium").on("click",function() {

med();
$("#medium").unbind("click");
$("#large").bind("click",function(){
    inc();
   });
   $("#small").bind("click",function(){
    small();
});

 });

 $("#small").on("click",function() {

small();
$("#small").unbind("click");
$("#large").bind("click",function(){
    inc();
});
  $("#medium").bind("click",function(){
      med();
  });

 });


});
```

Comment: `bind/unbind` are deprecated use please `on/off`..

Comment: Why not use `<button>` elements instead of `<a>`, so you can set the `disabled` property?

Comment: I like the result of clicking on small: it adds 0 pixels. I guess it will be useful for something, and I am just not getting it. Secondly, if you keep adding pixels with medium/large, at some point you'll not be able to notice the difference between a `h1` and `h4` text. You should really increase with a percentage, and not with a fixed pixel size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be more simple if you're use `data` attribute see the next example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.changefont').on('click' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ChangeFontSize($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});

function ChangeFontSize($vol){
  $('div').children().not('[data-vol="'+$vol+'"]').each(function(){
    var DataVol = $(this).data('vol'),
        FontSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size')),
        FontReset = DataVol == "small" ? 0 : DataVol == "medium" ? -1 :  DataVol == "large" ? -2 : 0,
        FontChange = $vol == "small" ? 0 : $vol == "medium" ? 1 :  $vol == "large" ? 2 : 0;
    $(this).data('vol' , $vol);
    $(this).css('font-size' , FontSize + FontReset + FontChange+'px');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="changefont" id="small">Small</a>
<a class="changefont" id="medium">Medium</a>
<a class="changefont" id="large">Large</a>


<div>
      <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
      <h4>ipsum dolor sit lorem</h4>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

**1st:** instead of using 3 functions and 3 click event you can just use 1 function and add the same class for `<a>` buttons and use just one click event

**2nd:** what the code do? it simply add the `data-vol` attribute to the elemetnt with small, medium and large volume .. read the comment in the code below

```
function ChangeFontSize($vol){  //pass volume of font here (small , medium or large) we will get this from the <a> id
  $('div').children().not([data-vol="'+$vol+'"]).each(function(){  //loop through the children but its data-vol attribute not with the same vol of button (it will prevent the same vol to click again)
    var DataVol = $(this).data('vol'),    // get the data-vol from the element 
        FontSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size')),   // get the font size of the element
        FontReset = DataVol == "small" ? 0 : DataVol == "medium" ? -1 :  DataVol == "large" ? -2 : 0,   // some shortcut if/else statement using the previous  DataVol  to reset the font size to its default
        FontChange = $vol == "small" ? 0 : $vol == "medium" ? 1 :  $vol == "large" ? 2 : 0;    // get the value to increase it to the font
    $(this).data('vol' , $vol);   // change data-vol attribute with the new font volume 
    $(this).css('font-size' , FontSize + FontReset + FontChange+'px');  // finally change the font 
  });
}
```

**Finally** you can simply add `.not("header div").not("footer div")` to this code to let it work fine as expected .. I didn't add it to make my example simple to understand

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution without bind/unbind https://jsfiddle.net/vcoaqcoh/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  inc = function(){
   $("div").not("header div").not("footer div").children().each(function() {
     var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
   size = size + 2 + "px";
     $(this).css({
    'font-size': size
    });
   });
  }

  med = function(){
  $("div").not("header div").not("footer div").children().each(function() {
     var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
     size = size + 1 + "px";
     $(this).css({
    'font-size': size
    });
   });
 }

  small = function(){
   $("div").not("header div").not("footer div").children().each(function() {
     var size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    size = size + 0 + "px";
     $(this).css({
    'font-size': size
     });
   });
 }

 $("#large").on("click",function() {
  inc();
  $("#large").addClass('removePointer');
    $("#medium, #small").removeClass('removePointer');
 });

  $("#medium").on("click",function() {
    med();
    $("#medium").addClass('removePointer');
    $("#large, #small").removeClass('removePointer');
 });

  $("#small").on("click",function() {
  small();
  $("#small").addClass('removePointer');
  $("#large, #medium").removeClass('removePointer');
 });
});
```

```css
.removePointer { 
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="small">Small</a>
<a id="medium">Medium</a>
<a id="large">Large</a>

<div>
  <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  <h4>ipsum dolor sit lorem</h4>
</div>
```

I've used a `css` **property** named `pointer-events`.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid binding and unbinding event handlers like that.

If your aim is to allow a kind of zoom-in/out, then adding pixels is not the right way to go. It does not maintain the "aspect ratio" of the different original font-sizes (`h1`, `h4`, ...). If you click on *medium* and then *large* and repeat that sequence 100 times, you will have added 300 pixels to the font sizes, which will hide the difference between these header sizes.

Instead, you'd be better of in dealing with a percentage of the original font sizes.

Here is how you could do that with a slider:

```js
$("#zoom").on("input", function () {
    $("#pct").text(this.value);
    $("#container").css({ fontSize: this.value + "%" });
});
$("#reset").on("click", function () {
    $("#zoom").val(100).trigger("input");
});
```

```css
#zoom { display: block; width: 97%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="zoom" min="10" max="200" value="100">
<div><span id="pct">100</span>% <button id="reset">Reset</button></div>

<div id="container">
    <h1>lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
    <h4>ipsum dolor sit lorem</h4>
</div>
```